# Google chrome: How to change the behavior about history logging and auto completion?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm a long time Firefox user, recently I have to use Google Chrome (GC) for my work because it has cooler developer tool. For a short trial period, I found that GC is pretty cool as it has many feature that Firefox doesn't have and I would like to switch to GC permanently. However, Firefox also has something I can't live without, which are:

1. Firefox saves everything you have ever visited, even just once. For example, I once visit a website I can't remember clearly it's address and title, except for two or three word from the title, with Firefox, I just type those word on the address bar and I can find the site again. GC can't do that as it only save sites you visit often I guess.
2. When you type on the address bar the address of the website you visit so many time, Firefox autocompletion suggest the homepage of the website first, while GC suggest the page you visit the most from that website. For example: when I type "you" on the address bar and hit Enter, I expect going to the homepage of youtube, but when using GC, I will always end up going to the clip I watched the most on youtube.

I'm hoping GC has some settings to make it behave like Firefox for cases I describe above, or at least some plugin/addon. Is there something like that?

Any help is gladly appreciated, thank you!